# Saving a .tar.gz file located on server to a FILE object

Tags: python, file, flask, tar

I'm currently working on a Python Flask API.

For demo purposes, I have a folder in the server containing .tar.gz files. 
Basically I'm wondering how do I save these files knowing their relative path name, say like `file.tar.gz`, into a `FILE` object. I need the tar file in the format to be able to run the following code on it, where `f` would be the tar file:

```
 tar = tarfile.open(mode="r:gz", fileobj=f)
 for member in tar.getnames():
    tf = tar.extractfile(member)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not ver familiar with this but , just saving it normally with .tar.gz extension should work? if yes and if you have the file already compressed then a very simple code could do that,

```
compresseddata= 'your file'
with open('file.tar.gz') as fo:
    fo.write(compressed data)
    fo.flush().close()
```

Will this do the job , or am i getting something wrong here?